# How to give Admin panel list view link (Docx file download) in Codigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

Actually,I'm working on Codigniter adminpanel modules,i'm implemented a module i want give download link in separate column how will give please help.

```
1) i Want (**Files List**) column need to give download link.
```

Here my code : views.php

```
 <table class="table table-hover" id="dataTables-tenant">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th><input type="checkbox" data-note="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Check/Uncheck all" class="check-all"></th>
                                  <th>File Name</th>
                                  <th>File title</th>
                                  <th>Files List</th>                                  
                                  <th>created at</th>
                                  <th>updated at</th>
                                  <!-- <a href="http://localhost/fre/admin/uploads/" download="w3logo">
                                  <img border="0" src="http://localhost/fre/admin/uploads/.'$Knowledge_id'" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
                                  </a> -->
                                  <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                       </table>
```

Script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oTable = $('#dataTables-tenant').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>loadTenant",
    "pageLength": 10,
    "aoColumnDefs"  : [
        {
          orderable: false,
          "mData": null,
          "aaSorting":false,
          "aTargets": [0],
          "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
              return '<input type="checkbox" value="'+full[0]+'" name="Knowledge_id" class="case selectionne uncheck"/>';
          },
         "sClass": 'selectall'
        },
        {
          orderable: false,
          "mData": null,
          "aaSorting":false,
          "aTargets": [6],
          "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
            return '<center><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>tenant/editNew/'+full[0]+'" data-note="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit Tenant Details" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" id="infrastructure_btn_edit"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" data-note="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete Room" data-Knowledge_id="'+full[0]+'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash deleteTenant"></a></center>';
          },
        },
    ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

create download file in your project and send data to this file

for example:

download.php

```html
<?php
// Save File
 $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
 $filename = "Perfomance_Appraisal.docx";
 $objWriter->save($filename);


// The following offers file to user on client side: deletes temp version of file
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
 flush();
// or echo($filename)
 readfile($filename);
 unlink($filename); // deletes the temporary file
```

You can also use the following library:

[GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)